# Need an easy to use 3d game engine

Tags: 3d, game-engine

I'm looking for a VERY easy to use 3d game engine. I want to program only the logic of the game, and don't want to have to concern myself with graphics. I just want to be able to download a model, put it in the game, and start programming the logic. I would preferable want to program in a scripting language like Python.

I just want to make the game for learning purposes, and not to show it to anyone (I'm still a student). Most of the engines I've looked at had a steep learning curve.

Please mention any 3d engine that would be suitable for me.

Thanks.

Comment: not a programming answer, but many games (Starcraft 2, Oblivion, Half-Life 2, etc) come with a pretty powerful level editor that includes whatever internal scripting language they use. You might want to start off making a mod with those tools instead of diving into coding your own game engine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at Unity 3D: http://unity3d.com/

Comment: +1 Unity is capable, sort of free, and has a large community and an active forum. Definitely worth a look.

Answer (score 4):

[Panda 3D](http://www.panda3d.org/) is used in education in a couple of schools.

Programming is not easy, game programming is harder, 3D game programming is even harder unless you go with a lot of canned stuff you are not going to find an "easy" out

Answer (score 1):

Soya 3D which is open source and very high level.

> Soya 3D is an object oriented "high level" 3D engine for Python. Somehow, Soya is to 3D what Python is to programming: an 'avant garde' 3D engine, a kind of 'UFO' in the 3D world :-). Soya allows to develop very rapidly games of other 3D apps, entirely in the Python language (contrary to most of the other engine, in which Python is limited to scripting tasks).

http://home.gna.org/oomadness/en/soya3d/index.html

I used it a lot when I was into python.

Answer (score 1):

try ursina is a very very simple library that you can use to write a simple 3d project.it so simple in fact you can make something like Minecraft with about 100-200 lines of code!
making Minecraft in python: https://youtu.be/DHSRaVeQxIk
documentation: https://www.ursinaengine.org/documentation.html
here is one of the demo projects code(Minecraft clone)

```
'''
Disclaimer: This solution is not scalable for creating a big world.
Creating a game like Minecraft requires specialized knowledge and is not as easy
to make as it looks.
You'll have to do some sort of chunking of the world and generate a combined mesh
instead of separate blocks if you want it to run fast. You can use the Mesh class for this.
You can then use blocks with colliders like in this example in a small area
around the player so you can interact with the world.
'''

from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController


app = Ursina()

# Define a Voxel class.
# By setting the parent to scene and the model to 'cube' it becomes a 3d button.

class Voxel(Button):
    def __init__(self, position=(0,0,0)):
        super().__init__(
            parent = scene,
            position = position,
            model = 'cube',
            origin_y = .5,
            texture = 'white_cube',
            color = color.color(0, 0, random.uniform(.9, 1.0)),
            highlight_color = color.lime,
        )


    def input(self, key):
        if self.hovered:
            if key == 'left mouse down':
                voxel = Voxel(position=self.position + mouse.normal)

            if key == 'right mouse down':
                destroy(self)


for z in range(8):
    for x in range(8):
        voxel = Voxel(position=(x,0,z))


player = FirstPersonController()
app.run()
```